# Audio not playing from discord bot into voice channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a simple discord bot that plays an audio clip into a channel. I have looked at several tutorials and ended up with this code below. The discord bot joins the channel and the circle lights up green, but no audio plays and the bot never leaves the channel unless I manually disconnect it. I have downloaded ffmpeg and set the environment variable path. I have installed the opus for discord.js as well. I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
require('dotenv').config()


const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const path = require('path');
var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("bot is just here chillin");
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    
  if  ((msg.content === 'chillin')||(msg.content === '/c')) {
    msg.channel.send(';)');
    var voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>{
        console.log('joined voice channel');
        const dispatcher = connection.play(require("path").join(__dirname, 'chillinCopy.mp3'));
        console.log('playing audio');
        dispatcher.on("end", end => {
            console.log('finished audio');
            voiceChannel.leave();});
       
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }


});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```